# How to convert all properties with a given type to another in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have

```js
type EmployeeDTO = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

and I want a **utility type** to convert all properties with the type of `Date` to `moment`

```js
type EmployeeDTO = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string;
  dateOfBirth: moment;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ModifyProp` below.
Here is [the sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=3&pln=22&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwJYDMQAUBOcwB4AqUEAHsBAHYIDOUA3gL4A0U+AYtgLbP75wB8UALx0AUFCgBtANJQk5KAGsIIOChYBdAFxQAosQDGAGwCuCCAWnrmxyhBRyICASTKUabTmKgB+Fry-aekam5viW1rb25I7OpBTUdPRevvDIaFg4FlJWLOxwXH78ASyWANwi9OUioJBQrHBwQqLiCACGZNoAIu0Q5eI4wEhw5K2G3WTeXT19UCgN2uTGHABGEJgzy62Yk1BUwJhyAOYz0XuO2rReLT1TZDP9YIPD4xA7L-ez81CLK2sfm9ttHsDuRjl4kkkRAB6ABUIku1w6UAA5Bx8hRgMiZgMhiMxj0dqj0eRMTM5nAFktVusvACdsCjicIGcEBcrlA2kiiRwMVj2TjngTtNzeR9yZTfjTxOI6UD9ozwRURDCodVwNBUqgkI56o1hJr0tg8LrmC9mCKSci+OUahrEFrHAA5ZlkBC6poG7VuhoSZGnV3I9TlIA)  to play around.

```js
type ModifyProp<T extends {}, TFrom, TTo> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends TFrom
  ? TTo
  : Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends {}
  ? ModifyProp<T[K], TFrom, TTo>
  : T[K];
};

type Foo = {
  date: Date;
  optionalDate?: Date;
  foo: number;
  bar?: string;
  nested: {
    date: Date;
    optionDate?: Date;
    foo: number;
    bar?: string;
  }
}

type ModifiedFoo = ModifyProp<Foo, Date, 'moment'>;
/*
{
  date: 'moment';
  optionalDate?: 'moment';
  foo: number;
  bar?: string;
  nested: {
    date: 'moment';
    optionDate?: 'moment';
    foo: number;
    bar?: string;
  }
}
*/
```

**NOTE**:
The code above goes with 2 additional test cases from the question which are:

- optional property *(That's why I use `Exclude<T[K], undefined>` instead of  `T[K]`)*
- and nested property *(That's why I add the condition `Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends {})`*.

The example code above demonstrates those 2 test cases already. Feel free to modify it to your need.

Comment: Clever, but is there really a use-case for this?  After all, if I want the modified type I can just copy/paste and then change the name and the appropriate properties, and it's arguable the code is then much clearer than what's above

Comment: @RichN It comes from a real use case of mine actually. The backend guy hands me *DTO types* with some property having `Date` as the type. And I have to use that DTO along with antd's `Form` and `Date Picker`. Unfortunately, `Date Picker` *(by default)* only accepts `moment.Moment`. If you feed it with `Date`, it will throw you an error. That's why I want to convert all `Date` to `moment.Moment`.

Comment: Refer to [this sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO0AiAVAeWQG8AoZC5YAEwH4AuZTMKUAc2QB9kBXEaiDFARqAbnKUe2KADk4AWwgMmLdl179BwsRIoAHOJkwB3APZQ6jZqxAdufAUJAjxlZBHlxgAG2XW19ppOLrru8nrepgCeEEqMqACi4ZExEPgErpTUcJAAwlAQOSLKOEXqDlrOOgC+pKSgkLCIKInJ0bHpJKE0yiA88gBG0JkUQlDMcop+qrblQdojyN6GYJNxKjZ2Go4LoXrQmKYgcN5JXr5WM1sVwTpuZlAA1mc+05tzO1WLegAWR+v+WaBT4hNzZSAEGAAIWAUDAPxKRUW2AAHm8AttKqDKHBqNQCkZ0UDMbdFggeFACuAAIJ4gmYInXeZfULHMDAI4nVCWDYYm67WqkIA) for DTO types I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to modify this to work converting from ex. `string[]` to `string`?

Messing around I believe both the `extends Array<any>` and `extends Record<string, any>` are not handling it correctly but it would be nice to still keep the recursion.

I

```
type HasStrArr = {
    strArr: string[];
}
type ModifyProp<T extends {}, TFrom, TTo> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends Array<any>
        ? ModifyProp<T[K], TFrom, TTo>
        : Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends Record<string, any>
        ? ModifyProp<T[K], TFrom, TTo>
        : Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends TFrom
        ? TTo
        : T[K];
};


type JustStrings = ModifyProp<HasStrArr,string[],string>

/* 
    {
        strArr: string[];
    }
 */
```